# Where does the current go in a half-wave rectifier?

Tags: diodes

A diode doesn't act as a resistor, so when you have an AC source that produces a half-wave when the current passes through it, where is that energy going if not in the form of dissipated heat through some kind of resistance?

Comment: You may want to expand that question to make it clearer what you are actually asking.

Comment: The current is not passing, that is.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me. Anyone with experience in electrical engineering knows what a diode is and they know what a half-wave rectifier is. Instead, you could simply ask about what you're unclear on, which is the entire basis for asking questions on stack exchange.

Comment: The diode "turns off" in the reversed direction.  Not until you reach the break down voltage (which you should avoid with normal diodes).  There is a small leakage current.  But in most applications this is ignored.

Comment: Are you asking about forward or backward biased diode?

Comment: Forward direction.

Comment: The \$I\cdot V_{forward}\$ is dissipated as heat. Simple as that.

Comment: It is not clear if you have a load if you are thinking there is current passing thought the diode event if there is no load. Plus your statement that a diode doesn't act as a resistor is not quite correct.

Comment: I usually use SPICE to answer questions like this for myself. Sometimes I will forget the basics of some circuit and it is easy to simulate it and see the answer.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  Diodes are one-way valves for current.  Ideal diodes don't dissipate any power.  However, it's hard to say whether this is relevant to your question or not.

Answer (score 1):

The current doesnt go anywhere, because no current flows. You can think of a diode as being like a switch. When the voltage is going the "right" way (positive at the anode and negative at the cathode), it acts like a closed switch. When the voltage is going the "wrong" way, it acts like an open switch. Since the switch is open, no current flows.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0MKGE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

edit: Hmm, not exactly what op was asking but oh well

Comment: Suppose the source was a sort of AC battery. If what you're saying is correct, then you're saying with 100% certainty that there would be no energy loss when the current flowed in the opposite direction, and your circuit could yield the same amount of energy dissipated over a load an rectified source but only over twice the time. Otherwise, someone else suggested this energy is dissipated as heat, and got 3 upvotes for it. So who's correct?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what they are saying, because your question is fairly unclear. There would be no *extra* energy loss there, and the "AC battery" would "yield the same amount of energy dissipated over a load an rectified source but only over twice the time". What they are saying is that, when current *is* flowing (i.e. when the diode is forward biased, like in R2), the diode will dissapate some energy as heat. When current isn't flowing (i.e. the diode is reverse biased, R3), the diode will disappate no energy (apart from leakage current, which varies depending on diode type).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are asking about this circuit and calling it a half wave rectifier and wondering how it can rectify if there is no current...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffWAoz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Unfortunately, this circuit is NOT a half wave rectifier. It does not become a half wave rectifier till you attach some form of load.

In reality, with no load, the circuit is equivalent to this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWtGHE.png)</sup>

Now you may be saying, "But when I attach my scope I can clearly see a half wave signal..", and that would be correct. However, your scope provides the required load to allow the diode to act like a diode.